# Unable to get the value from a generic list<T>

Tags: c#

How to get the first and last element of a generic list of a custom type.

Hi, I have this generic list in my code

I want to pass the values that has been added into the list week1 to a function, but I can't even print out the values or when I assign it to another DateTime variable.

Simple thing like `Response.Write(week1[0])` does not work, I even tried `(week1.First())`, but the foreach loop works like a charm. I don't want that, I actually only need the first and the last date between the week.

```
List<Week> week1 = new List<Week>();
List<Week> week2 = new List<Week>();
List<Week> week3 = new List<Week>();
List<Week> week4 = new List<Week>();
List<Week> week5 = new List<Week>();

public class Week
{
    //this class has a default constructor
    public DateTime datefortheweek { get; set; }
}

//this works fine
foreach(Week text in week1)
{
    Response.Write(text.datefortheweek);
    Response.Write("<br/>");
}
```

Comment: did you input Week on list?

Comment: Why doesn't work `week1.First()`? What's the code and what's the error?

Comment: `Response.Write(week1[0])` and `Response.Write(week1.First())` are dissimilar to `Response.Write(text.datefortheweek);`. In the first two the `ToString()` method of `Week` will be called. In the latter, you are returning the `datefortheweek` property's value. Perhaps if you were testing like for like you would get the same results?

Comment: It isn't clear what the issue is or what you're trying to do.  Can you elaborate and clarify?  In what way does `Response.Write(week1[0])` not work?  If you only want the first and last, why not use `.First()` and `.Last()`?

Comment: Did you add items to the lists?
Also do you just need the first and last date of a week in a specific year or range?

Comment: @Amy, I was not getting any error, the page was just returning WebApplication1.Week when I try this out Response.Write(week1[0]) or when I tried Response.Write(week1.First());

Comment: @Baklap4 - I did, if (weeknum == 1)
                {
                    week1.Add(new Week() { datefortheweek = date1 });
                }

Comment: I really think you should reconsider the naming to clarify what you want and what your are actually doing. A collection of `Week`s should of course be named in plural, and the loop should be like `foreach (Week week in weeks)`. Other that, does the list week1 really contains any `Week` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
Response.Write(week1[0].datefortheweek)
```

or

```
Response.Write(week1.First().datefortheweek)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Response.Write(week1[0])` not working is probably because `Response.Write` does not take a `Week` as an argument.

If you look closely, your `foreach` loop approach uses `text.datefortheweek` instead of just `text`. You should also access `datefortheweek` after `week[0]`, and it should work:

```
Response.Write(week1[0].datefortheweek);
Response.Write(week1[week1.Length - 1].datefortheweek);
```

I also suggest that you use a 2D array/list to store `Week`s. This saves you the time of writing `week1`, `week2`, `week3` ... `weekX`.

```
List<List<Week>> weeks = new List<List<Week>>();
weeks.Add(new List<Week>());
weeks.Add(new List<Week>());
weeks.Add(new List<Week>());
...
```

Comment: thank you so much, that solved it, on the suggestion to use a 2 D array, are you saying that I should convert the list to an array once it gets filled up ?

Comment: @Cally No. I said you should use a 2D array _or_ 2D `List`.